# how to slide(translatetransition) listview in javafx

Tags: listview, animation, javafx

i have a listview with custom fxml view. everything is fine. now i want to show my all items automatically as like slide show. i try using translatetransition on list view. it do what i wanted but problem is when listview contains more items and need to scroll, then it only translate 1 or 2 items which normally show as listview without scrolling. **it means i able to translate only listview default view area but others items which hide as need to scrol do't show.**

> My translationtransition code is below:

```
    t = new TranslateTransition(Duration.seconds(10), listView);
    t.setToY(-(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight() + 500));
    t.setAutoReverse(true);
    t.setCycleCount(TranslateTransition.INDEFINITE);
    t.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it doesn't show all items. There simply are not more `ListCell`s than shown on screen (+maybe a few that are close enough to the viewport).

Usually to just show a cell you can call the `scrollTo` method. However if you want to control scroll speed, this isn't an option.

You need to adjust the scroll position you could get access to the `ScrollBar` though and use a `Timeline` animation to change it's value:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ListView<Integer> listView = new ListView<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        listView.getItems().add(i);
    }

    Button btn = new Button("start/stop scrolling");

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(listView, btn));

    // make sure skin is created
    listView.applyCss();
    listView.layout();

    // assuming vertical listview here
    ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) listView.lookup(".scroll-bar:"+listView.getOrientation().toString().toLowerCase());

    DoubleProperty pos = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    DoubleBinding scrollValueBinding
            = scrollBar.maxProperty().subtract(scrollBar.minProperty()).multiply(pos).add(scrollBar.minProperty());

    Timeline timeline = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO, new KeyValue(pos, 0d)),
            new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5), new KeyValue(pos, 1d))
    );

    scrollBar.visibleProperty().addListener((observable, wasVisible, isVisible) -> {
        if (!isVisible) {
            // stop when scrollbar disappears
            timeline.pause();
        }
    });
    timeline.statusProperty().addListener((observable, oldStatus, newStatus) -> {
        if (newStatus == Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
            scrollBar.setDisable(true);
            scrollBar.valueProperty().bind(scrollValueBinding);
        } else if (oldStatus == Animation.Status.RUNNING) {
            scrollBar.setDisable(false);
            scrollBar.valueProperty().unbind();
        }
    });

    timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
    timeline.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

    btn.setOnAction(evt -> {
        if (timeline.getStatus() == Animation.Status.RUNNING || !scrollBar.isVisible()) {
            timeline.pause();
        } else {
            // only run if not already running and scrollbar is visible
            Duration total = timeline.getCycleDuration();
            timeline.playFrom(total.multiply((scrollBar.getValue() - scrollBar.getMin()) / (scrollBar.getMax() - scrollBar.getMin())));
        }
    });

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: **i am getting null pointer on this line** 'DoubleBinding scrollValueBinding
                = scrollBar.maxProperty().subtract(scrollBar.minProperty()).multiply(pos).add(scrollBar.minProperty());'